# "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found in monoDevelop IDE on kali linux 2020

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, mono, monodevelop

I am new to c# programming and specially new to mono compiler and mono related things on linux. when i wrote

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

on mono develop IDE and hit the build button i am getting

```
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB4019: The imported project 
"/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. 
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019) (HelloWorld)
```

this error. i did some research i can't understand any solution because i am completely beginner to mono c# programming on linux

Comment: Have you upgraded to MonoDevelop 7.8.4.1? That error is caused by mismatch Mono and MonoDevelop versions. To really learn C# on Linux, install VSCode and .NET Core SDK please, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

Comment: i installed MonoDevelop 7.8.4(which is latest on MonoDevelop official page) but still getting same shit

Comment: @LexLi Thank you by the way I setup development env in VSCode and .NET for c# like you told.

Answer (score 0):

I used to meet " couldn't find Microsoft.CSHARP.Targets".
And the solution is to change it as "Microsoft.Csharp.targets".
So maybe you can try the same way.